# Can I use link_selections with combined plots in Holoviews?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, holoviews

I would like to link selections across several elements, one of which is actually a 'Overlay' (typically `plot1*plot2`). However, I have not been able to make it work.

Indeed, after being initialized link_selections is set by passing as an argument a layout that contains elements sharing the same Dataset. For instance, looking at the example provided by Holoviews in [the user guide](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Linked_Brushing.html):

```
w_accel_scatter = hv.Scatter(autompg_ds, 'weight', 'accel')
mpg_hist = histogram(autompg_ds, dimension='mpg', normed=False).opts(color="green")
violin = hv.Violin(autompg_ds, [], 'hp')

mpg_ls = link_selections.instance()    
mpg_ls(w_accel_scatter + mpg_hist + violin)
```

In my case I would like to display, say, `w_accel_scatter*line_plot + mpg_hist + violin` (with `line_plot` using other data), while retaining the selection link between `w_accel_scatter`, `mpg_hist` and `violin`:
[image: Structure of the desired layout.]

The problem is that calling `mpg_ls()` actually triggers the display of what is passed as an argument and obviously `mpg_ls(w_accel_scatter*other_plot + mpg_hist + violin)` won't work.

Btw I am working within a notebook and using the bokeh backend. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "`calling mpg_ls() actually triggers the display of what is passed as an argument`".  Returning an object as the value of a cell is what triggers the display, not mpg_ls, so you should be able to keep working after your mpg_ls call. You just need to capture the result of your mpg_ls call, and then you can work with it until you eventually have something you want to display.

In any case, because nothing should be displayed immediately when you do `mpg_ls()`, you can pass each object you want linked to `mpg_ls` independently, linking each of the ones you want to link, then put them all into whatever overlay or layout you want.

ETA an example of doing precisely that:

```
mpg_ls = link_selections.instance()
other_plot = hv.Curve(([2000,4000,5000], [10,15,25])).opts(color="red")
mpg_ls(w_accel_scatter)*other_plot + mpg_ls(mpg_hist) + mpg_ls(violin)
```

[image: Screenshot showing linked_selections with overlays]

Here we specifically link only those plots that are related to each other, and not the unrelated `other_plot`. We should clarify how to do this in the docs, because it's not obvious! Also, I would have expected `mpg_ls(w_accel_scatter*other_plot + mpg_hist + violin)` to work, which I'll file as an issue on HoloViews.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

I would have assumed mpg_ls would only be a kind of 'link' object between elements, but `mpg_ls(w_accel_scatter + mpg_hist + violin)` actually returns the display. I don't know the underlying code but a more intuitive way for me would be to pass a list of elements to be linked, and then build an arbitrary layout.

Using `mpg_ls(w_accel_scatter*other_plot + mpg_hist + violin)` does not work (how can it know which element of the overlay the link should apply to?). I get the correct layout but the link is not there. I've also tried passing each element to mpg_ls in turn.

Comment: It sounds like you're not quite appreciating how HoloViews works. mpg_ls does not return the display, it returns a HoloViews object. In turn, HoloViews objects display themselves, if they are the last item in a Jupyter Notebook cell. At no point in the mpg_ls call is anything actually displayed. Instead, displaying is something that is triggered by a "display hook" in Jupyter, such that if an object is returned from a cell (whether the object is a number or a string or an hv objet) it is displayed.

Comment: So just like "int(3.5)" displays "3" despite "int" having nothing to do with display, mpg_ls does not display anything; it returns something that could be displayed. In both cases whatever the cell ends up with is displayed, and for mpg_ls it's an hv object that then displays as a plot.

Comment: Here, it sounds like you are reporting a bug, because mpg_ls indeed should link all the elements given to it, and you can indeed then put them together in a layout. So please focus on the concrete difference between the expected and actual behavior.  Expected: I passed this set of objects to be linked, Observed: only some were linked, none were linked, or whatever you observed.

Comment: Indeed I did not pay attention to the place where the call to mpg_ls was in my notebook cell. But even with this in mind the issue is still there: I cannot build a layout with the selection link after I called mpg_ls (in fact even with the original 3 elements only, so it has nothing to do with overlays). It looks like the only way to have that link is to display the mpg_ls object itself, maybe it cannot work otherwise. I thought it might be a limitation of Holoviews but before I submit a bug report / feature request I like to make sure the problem does not come from my code.

Comment: ETA an example of what I mean above, showing that linking the individual bits works fine. I would also have expected the overlay to simply ignore the unrelated data automatically, but apparently not.

Comment: I've filed a report asking for that to be supported or at least to get a warning (https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/4662).

Comment: Thanks, that works. However now I realize that the link_selections apparently breaks the hover tools of the constituting elements.

Comment: If you can make a reproducible example for any specific issues like that, please file a bug report at github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues. Thanks!